# MacOS 10.15 Beta and CraftCMS

Tags: php

i'm running a macOS 10.15 Beta (to check out SwiftUI) but now i'm running into problems with craft, specifically with the php zip extension.

It's PHP 7.3.5 and i can't update it, because the install process doesn't recognize my system as an macOS above 10.6 :/

Has anyone an idea how to get the craft installation running under macOS 10.15 or how to fix the specific problem with the missing php zip extension?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In the new MacOS version, the 32-bit support was dropped. This could be a possible explanation.
Can you report us the error message?

Comment: That's i get after "composer create-project craftcms/craft ."

Problem 1
- craftcms/cms 3.2.1 requires ext-zip * -> the requested PHP extension zip is missing from your system.
- craftcms/cms 3.2.0 requires ext-zip * -> the requested PHP extension zip is missing from your system.
- craftcms/cms 3.1.9.1 requires ext-zip * -> the requested PHP extension zip is missing from your system.

… and so on ;)

Comment: Have you tried to uninstall and install php@7.3? I'm also on macOS 10.15 (19A471t) and php7.3 and Craft works as expected.

Comment: i tried to install php with homebrew but that doesn't work either because of an old Xcode Version (couldn't update with beta, use xcode-beta) so i find now way to update.

Can i update the system php in usr/bin/php? how?

Comment: Then you should make sure that brew is working. What brew error are you getting?

Comment: Your XCode (10.1) is too outdated. But i can't update to 10.2 with the beta dev apple-id. Whren i remove the old xcode (because i only use the beta version) brew needs updated command line tools for python ... one solution forces another problem :/

Comment: and brew doesn't install php as a package :( just the dependencies expect the xcode error ...

Comment: Do you have Xcode 11 installed? Then maybe this solves your problem. https://discourse.brew.sh/t/mac-os-10-15-catalina-issues/5001/12

Comment: I have XCode 11 + Command Line Tools installed. The problem there doesn't relate to my situation i think. I update the 10.1 XCode now to 10.2 and i'll see if i can then install php with brew... maybe that will work out.

Comment: @Fred Now I get this when I install php via Homebrew:
==> Installing php dependency: python
Warning: Building python from source:
  The bottle needs the Apple Command Line Tools to be installed.
  You can install them, if desired, with:
    xcode-select --install

xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
Error: An exception occurred within a child process:
  CompilerSelectionError: python cannot be built with any available compilers.
Install GNU's GCC:
  brew install gcc